# Can malware module be signed as Microsoft Corporation module?

Tags: malware, forensics, code-signing

In this security tutorial:
https://youtu.be/dykc9YC9Z6U?t=257

the author claims that "sihost is a network component of the malware..." (at 4:23). Yet, prior to his claim, at 3:09 he shows that that particular `sihost` is signed as Microsoft binary. So, it ought to be a Windows system module, correct?

I [have read here](https://www.zdnet.com/article/these-hackers-used-microsoft-signed-malicious-drivers-to-further-their-ransomware-attacks/) that some bad dev suppliers had their malicious code signed by Microsoft in the past through its attestation signing process, but even then (if I understand correctly) the binary would have been signed by Microsoft with the name of the malicious dev company, not with the name of Microsoft themselves.

So, is it possible for a malware binary to be signed as Microsoft Corporation binary?